# Django is not hitting my CustomAuthMiddleware

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to implement a custom auth using `RemoteUserMiddleware`
My `settings.py` has:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'my_app.backends.custom_auth.CustomHeaderMiddleware',
 )
```

And `backends.custom_auth.py`

```
class CustomHeaderMiddleware(RemoteUserMiddleware):    
    header = "CUSTOM_USERID"
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("...")
        try:
            username = request.META[self.header]
        except KeyError:
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                try:
                    stored_backend = load_backend(request.session.get(
                        auth.BACKEND_SESSION_KEY, ''))
                    if isinstance(stored_backend, RemoteUserBackend):
                        auth.logout(request)
                except ImproperlyConfigured as e:
                    # backend failed to load
                    auth.logout(request)
            return

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.user.get_username() == self.clean_username(username, request):
                return
        user = auth.authenticate(remote_user=username)
        if user:
            request.user = user
            auth.login(request, user)
```

I'm testing this locally, and `request.META['CUSTOM_USERID']` is set. But CustomHeaderMiddleware.process_request is not being hit. 
I want the user to be checked whenever the `CUSTOM_USERID` key is present.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you added `CustomHeaderMiddleware` to you `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting?

Comment: Ummm, no. Thanks for that @Ian Shelvington!!!

Comment: Can I ask a related question? I want to fall back to `auth.backends.ModelBackend` if the `remote_user` isn't set. But when I try adding it in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` I get an error "'CustomHeaderMiddleware' object has no attribute 'authenticate'". I should be able to do this, right?

Comment: OK, I guess I have to have `ModelBackend` first. That's a little counterintuitive to me, but I guess I get it.